# Typescript is giving me an error: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-context

I want to define the interface the proper way but I am having trouble because it is expecting an argument even though the argument is empty.

I am using `useContext` and I defined the interface like this:

```
    //react-auth0-spa.tsx
    interface Auth0Context {
        ......
        loginWithRedirect:  () => void; //I know this is the problem but I don't know what to define.
        ......
     }
```

in the provider, the `value` is :

```
 //react-auth0-spa.tsx
 <Auth0Context.Provider
     value=({
  ....
  loginWithRedirect: (...p: string[]) => auth0Client.loginWithRedirect(...p)
   ....
   })
>
```

now, I `import` the context to other the other file like so:
`const { isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect, logout } = useAuth0()`

and this is where the error occurs

```
///components/NavBar.tsx
const { isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect, logout } = useAuth0()
<div>
      {!isAuthenticated && (
        <button onClick={() => loginWithRedirect({})}>Log in</button> //Expected 0 arguments, but got 1
      )}
</div>
```

so the problem is `loginWithRedirect` is expecting 1 argument, but `() => loginWithRedirect({})` is an empty object. The problem can be solved by using `any` inside the interface but what should I put if I want to define it explicitly?

I tried `loginWithRedirect:  ({}) => void` but now `loginWithRedirect: (...p: string[]) => auth0Client.loginWithRedirect(...p)` is giving me error like this `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)`

source code without typescript is https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-react-samples/tree/master/01-Login/src

Please help.

Comment: Your question title and description are bit contradictory.

Title says it's expecting 0 arguments means it's not expecting any argument at all.

Description says it's expecting 1 argument.

Comment: what is the type of the argument that `loginWithRedirect` can be called with ?

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear. what I need is to change the interface `loginWithRedirect:  () => void;` so that I can use `<button onClick={() => loginWithRedirect({})}>` Which means I need to provide an argument in the interface which I don't know how to do

Comment: @Ali I have used `loginWithRedirect: any; ` in the interface and it is working. The thing is, I need to explicitly define it. The problem I'm facing is, how can I define an argument in the interface if it's empty? `<button onClick={() => loginWithRedirect({})}`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Problem** in the first place is:

You provided signature of a function like this in the interface:

`loginWithRedirect:  () => void;`

which means *no argument* and whenever you'll define that function you will *obey* this signature but in contrary you are passing argument to the function while giving it's definition.

**Solution**

Why not doing like this?

```
//react-auth0-spa.tsx
    interface Auth0Context {
        ......
        loginWithRedirect:  (p: object) => void;
        ......
     }
```

Comment: Yes, I provided it like this `loginWithRedirect:  () => void;` but what I need to do is change the interface so it will accept `onClick={() => loginWithRedirect({})}` . That way, I will have 1 argument to satisfy typescript

Comment: @bradrar but that one argument's type must be match with the argument's type in signature of the function.

Comment: Yes, But I don't know how. I have read the docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html about functions but the examples here have parameters, in my case, the function is empty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,I tried it and now `onClick={() => loginWithRedirect({})}`  error is `Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'.
  Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'string[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.ts(2345)`

Comment: @bradrar I've updated the answer, can you give it a try

Comment: Thank you! your previous answer gave me a clue!  So what I did is `loginWithRedirect:  ({}:object) => void;` it is now working properly. Your answer is working as well. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I was doing is didn't mention the parameter type, like undernetah

```
interface Props {
  openSnackbarHandler: () => void
}
export const app:React.FC<Props> = ({ openSnackbarHandler }) => {

   openSnackbarHandler("Password has been changed successfully!")

}

// method passed as props
const openSnackbarHandler: (mesg: string) => {
         console.log(mesg);
}
```

just define the type in parameter:

```
interface Props {
  openSnackbarHandler: (mesg: string) => void
}
```